# Import multiple xlsx file in R

Tags: r

I have several xlsx files in a directory with the same structure (i.e. column A,B,C); every file is the data of one day.
I need to import all the data in R and find the differences between one day and the next one.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx")
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
    assign(paste("Day", i, sep = "."), read.xlsx(files[i]))
}
```

I can't figure out how to use the imported data.
For example

```
Day.1 <- data.frame(Day.1)
Day.1$A <- as.character(Day.1$A)
Day.2 <- data.frame(Day.2)
Day.2$A <- as.character(Day.2$A)
anti_join (Day.1, Day.2)
```

This code works fine but how should it be with a variable?

```
Day.[i] <- data.frame(Day.[i])
Day.[i]$A <- as.character(Day.[i]$A)
Day.[i+1] <- data.frame(Day.[i+1])
Day.[i+1]$A <- as.character(Day.[i+1]$A)
anti_join (Day.[i], Day.[i+1])
```

---

I tried to import all the files in a single data frame but I have a similar problem about how to use the new data

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
days.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
days <- rbindlist(days.list, idcol = "id")
days <- data.frame(days)
days$B <- as.character(days$B)
```

But I don't know how to do something like:

```
day1 <- filter(days, id==1)
day2 <- filter(days, id==2)
diff1 <- anti_join (day1, day2, by=c("B", "C"))
```

using a counter variable (i)

```
day(i) <- filter(days, id==(i))
day(i+1) <- filter(days, id==(i+1))
diff1 <- anti_join (day1, day2, by=c("B", "C"))
```

Comment: There are numerous examples on SO to do this properly (and not treat R like python with `for` loops). You should consider researching a bit more on how to use vectorized functions to make a big data frame and then easily group and do diffs between days.

Comment: Please include all `library` lines as a few methods here are not base R.

Comment: library(data.table)  and library(openxlsx)

Comment: And what about `library(dplyr)`? And what package is `read_excel`? Why is this changed from `for` loop's `read.xlsx`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using base R's `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) between a dataframe list of (*days*) and (*days + 1*), respectively the left and right sides of `dplyr::anti_join`. Of course the very last day will not have a forward day comparison.

```
library(xlsx)
library(dplyr)

file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, function(f){
    read.xlsx(f, 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})

left_days <- df.list[1:length(df.list)-1]    # SUBSET OUT LAST DAY
right_days <- df.list[2:length(df.list)]     # SUBSET OUT FIRST DAY 

# WITHOUT ARGS
anti_join_list <- Map(anti_join, left_days, right_days)

# WITH ARGS
anti_join_list <- Map(function(x,y) anti_join(x, y, by=c("B", "C")), left_days, right_days)
```